# Function is not called in xunit c#

Tags: c#, azure-functions, xunit

I created a unit test for an azure function which is below (azure funtion)

```
public class Processor
{
    private readonly static TimeSpan _TimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 4, 30);
    private readonly IHandler<Request> _Classifier;

    public Processor(IHandler<Request> Classifier)
    {
        _Classifier = Classifier;
    }

    [FunctionName("Processor")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *", RunOnStartup = false)] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        await _Classifier.ProcessCall(new string[] { "AR" }, 100, _TimeSpan);

    }

}
```

And in unit test checking a repository function is called or not.

```
public class ProcessorTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IRepository> _RepositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository>();
    private readonly Mock<IHandler<Request>> _Classifier;

    public ProcessorTests()
    {
        _Classifier = new Mock<IHandler<Request>>();
    }

    private Processor GetSetup()
    {
        return new Processor(_Classifier.Object);
    }

  
    [Fact]
    public async Task Getcall_check()
    {
        GivenCode();
        var sut = GetSetup();
        await sut.Run(null);
        _RepositoryMock.Verify(x => x.GetCodeFinder(It.IsAny<IList<string>>(), It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
    }


    private void GivenCode()
    {
        _RepositoryMock
            .Setup(m => m.GetCodeFinder(It.IsAny<IList<string>>() ,It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(new Response<Call>(false, null, Enumerable.Empty<CallOut>()));
    }
}
```

unit test is failed . when I debug the issue, this function _Classifier.ProcessCall does not get called. I put some breakpoints inside the _Classifier.ProcessCall but it's not received there. GetCodeFinder function is actually inside the ProcessCall..
I don`t understand why it not called ? any help

```
 public interface IHandler<TCode>
    {
        Task ProcessCallouts(IEnumerable<string> countryCodes, int batchSize, TimeSpan safeShutDownTimeSpan);
    }



public class Handler<TCode> : IHandler<TCode>
{
    private readonly IRepository _Repository;
    private readonly IServiceV2<Code, TCode> _Service;

    public Handler(
        IRepository repository,
        IServiceV2<Code, TCode> Service,
        )
    {
        _Repository = repository;
        _Service = Service;
      
    }
 

    public async Task Process(IEnumerable<string> countryCodes, int batchSize, TimeSpan safeShutDownTimeSpan)
    {
       
            
      var Response = await _Repository.GetCodeFinder(code, time, pageToken, batchSize);
               
    }
```

Comment: "I put some breakpoints inside the _Classifier.ProcessCall but it's not received there" - how have you done that, given that the classifier you're using is a mock? Where *exactly* have you put breakpoints?

Comment: "GetCodeFinder function is actually inside the ProcessCall" - not when you've set it up with a mock it's not. Is that in some implementation of `IHandler<Request>` that you haven't shown us? If so, how do you expect that to be used in the test? How do you expect any production code to use your `_RepositoryMock` field?

Comment: inside the actual function

Comment: Which "actual function"? Which class? (It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] but it feels like you've missed the fact that you're mocking out the `IHandler<T>` rather than using an actual implementation...)

Comment: I added IHandler<T> service in question. Also tried with the actual function. but not working. give me a sample please

Comment: Hint: in your test code, what do you expect to create an instance of the `Handler` class? I think you really need to review what mocking is for and what it does...

Comment: that i understand now. But how can I unit test GetCodeFinder

Comment: Well we haven't even seen the class that contains GetCodeFinder... you're currently mocking the repository. Basically, you should only mock the dependencies of the part you're trying to test.

Comment: tell me at least how to call the ProcessCall and hit the GetFinder method?

Comment: Well you'd need to create an instance of `Handler<TCode>` with the *actual* implementation of `IRepository`. Currently *neither* of those is happening...

Comment: That doesn't really provide any more information. I'm afraid at this stage I think you really need to take a step back, make sure you understand both your own code *and* the purpose of mocking. If you have a colleague who could walk through this with you, that would probably help. At the moment the question isn't really suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: okay.. I am a student. Not a professional. I just learning the new coding languages for my college project .. I am going to delete the question.. Thank you for your time